# Spending charged Facebook credits on iPhone app is allowed?

Tags: ios, facebook-credits

I'm working on Facebook Canvas Game project together with iPhone Native Game App which are using Facebook credits as a sole virtual currency.

It's known to us that "Purchasing Facebook credits on iOS native app" is not allowed by Apple In-app-purchase policy.

But how about just spending Facebook credits already purchased from website, on iOS native app? I guess that it might be ok, but not sure about this. Sadly, there are no explicit mention of Facebook or Apple about these things. Is there someone who can confirm about just spending(using) problem this question?

---

I found some news about this questions. May be helpful?

http://allthingsd.com/20110606/surprise-facebook-credits-and-apples-itunes-play-nice-with-each-other/

---

Recently I found that Facebook's Pay Dialog is just working on canvas iframe only and related payment Graph API were found from their document. Frictionless Payment which can be triggered on server-side, might be deprecated by Facebook.

> Note: that if you’ve already implemented the frictionless API on your
>   games' items, these items should not be affected; however, once
>   Auto-Frictionless Payments is ramped to 100 percent of users, we
>   encourage you to deprecate your use of this API, and just use our
>   standard payment flow which will automatically default to a
>   frictionless payment for items under 100 credits.
>   from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/

Comment: So does this mean that MMORPGs are no-gos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Partner Engineer at Facebook working on credits and I can confirm that Apple does not allow ANY other purchases to be made with other payment providers within native iOS applications. We hope to eventually release credits for virtual goods on websites, but not to native iOS applications.